# backbone events triggered arbitrary number of times

Tags: javascript, backbone-events

New to backbone, I'm approaching it with trivial example but i'm stuck on events triggering.

In my page i GET some data from the server and initialize a view with them. 
Then i can change the data through a form, they are saved to the server and the template is updated soon after with the new data. The data are fetched, saved and the view is updated but I can see through the console that the render function is called sometime twice, sometime even 4 times! And the call to the server, too, is made up to for time as GET, PUT, GET, GET.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="modelTpl">
<ul>
    <li><strong>Nome:</strong> {{nome}}</li>
    <li><strong>Cogome:</strong> {{cognome}}</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="nome" />
<input type="text" id="cognome" />
<a id="changeBtn">Modifica</a>
</script>


Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'server/model.php/model',
    defaults: {
        nome: "",
        cognome: ""
    }
});
var model = new Model({id: 1});

View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#wrapper',
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#modelTpl').html()),
    events: {
        "click #changeBtn": "change"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
        console.log('render');
        var self = this;
        this.model.fetch({
            error: function(model, response, options) { },
            success: function(model, response, options) {
                var data = model.toJSON();
                self.$el.html(self.template(data));
            }
        });
        return this;
    },
    change: function() {
        var n = this.$('#nome').val();
        var c = this.$('#cognome').val();
        this.model.save({ nome: n, cognome: c }, {
            error: function(model, response, options) { },
            success: function(model, response, options) { }
        });
    }
});

var view = new View({ model: model });
```

Comment: Try listening for "sync" event instead of "change" event for your backbone model.

Comment: it's even worse. The render function goes in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer this question now. However it may help other, so try _.debounce

```
this.change = _.debounce(this.change, 300);
```